# Food safety of cooked Lasagna that has been left on a counter and uncovered for 18 hours

Tags: food-safety

Food safety of cooked Lasagna that has been left on a counter and uncovered for 18 hours. What is the proper amount of time it can be left out of frig, and safe to eat as a leftover the next day.

Comment: As the answer on the duplicate says, more like two hours, once it's cooled below 140F.